# How to get around the scope of the foreach loop in Perl

Tags: arrays, perl, variables, scope

So I'm working through a bit of code that my compiler really doesn't like. There are two arrays, that have an identical number of indexes. `@array` is populated with `0`'s, `@otherarray` is populated sequentially. In this foreach loop, it skips over the first value because it is filled outside the loop. Count is declared as 1 outside the loop as well.

```
foreach (@array) {
    if ($count == 1) {
    } elsif($_ == 0 && @otherarray[$count-1] != undef) {
        $_ = $count;
        splice(@otherarray, @otherarray[$count - 1], 1);
    } else {
        $_ = $otherarray[ rand @otherarray ];
    }
$count++
}
```

It insists that I have use of uninitialized value in numeric ne(!=) on this line, and every line in which other array is inside an else/if/elsif statement:

```
elsif($_ == 0 && @otherarray[$count-1] != undef)
```

How do I work around this? I'm sure it's obvious but I'm really new to Perl, so I'm probably setting something up wrong in the first place? I have already declared my `@otherarray`.

Comment: Use `$` rather than `@` to access elements in an array

Comment: sidenote, `for my $count (0 .. $#array)` instead of `$count++`

Comment: By the way, is this a weird attempt at trying to shuffle a list? Why not use [`List::Util's shuffle`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?List%3A%3AUtil#shuffle_LIST)?

Comment: Still not too sure what you're trying to do here - could you edit your code/description to clarify?

Answer (score 4):

It is the `undef` in the comparison which is uninitialized. Use [`defined`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/defined.html) instead of comparing to `undef`:

```
elsif($_ == 0 && defined($otherarray[$count-1]))
```